# ElasticSearch MappingParsingException failed to parse string with colon

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I'm creating an ElasticSearch River that pulls metadata from a CMIS compliant repository like Alfresco. I have a string that contains a colon and it looks like ES is trying to cast the string to a number. Can anyone help with an object mapper than can handle this JSON string?

Exception:

```
org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: failed to parse [propertyData.values]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.AbstractFieldMapper.parse(AbstractFieldMapper.java:418)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper.serializeValue(ObjectMapper.java:636)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper.serializeArray(ObjectMapper.java:624)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper.parse(ObjectMapper.java:481)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper.serializeObject(ObjectMapper.java:537)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper.serializeArray(ObjectMapper.java:614)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper.parse(ObjectMapper.java:481)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapper.parse(DocumentMapper.java:515)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapper.parse(DocumentMapper.java:462)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.service.InternalIndexShard.prepareIndex(InternalIndexShard.java:394)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportShardBulkAction.shardIndexOperation(TransportShardBulkAction.java:413)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportShardBulkAction.shardOperationOnPrimary(TransportShardBulkAction.java:155)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$AsyncShardOperationAction.performOnPrimary(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:534)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$AsyncShardOperationAction$1.run(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:433)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "cmis:document"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:441)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:483)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.support.AbstractXContentParser.longValue(AbstractXContentParser.java:145)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.LongFieldMapper.innerParseCreateField(LongFieldMapper.java:297)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.NumberFieldMapper.parseCreateField(NumberFieldMapper.java:224)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.AbstractFieldMapper.parse(AbstractFieldMapper.java:408)
    ... 16 more
```

JSON:

```
{
    "objectId": "workspace://SpacesStore/cc8c446f-ac4e-40e5-b040-08f1030b708e",
    "propertyData": [
        {
            "displayName": "Content Stream Length",
            "extensions": null,
            "firstValue": 39914,
            "id": "cmis:contentStreamLength",
            "localName": "contentStreamLength",
            "queryName": "cmis:contentStreamLength",
            "values": [
                39914
            ]
        },
        {
            "displayName": "Object Type Id",
            "extensions": null,
            "firstValue": "cmis:document",
            "id": "cmis:objectTypeId",
            "localName": "objectTypeId",
            "queryName": "cmis:objectTypeId",
            "values": [
                "cmis:document"
            ]
        },
        {
            "displayName": "Version Series Checked Out By",
            "extensions": null,
            "firstValue": null,
            "id": "cmis:versionSeriesCheckedOutBy",
            "localName": "versionSeriesCheckedOutBy",
            "queryName": "cmis:versionSeriesCheckedOutBy",
            "values": []
        },
        {
            "displayName": "Version Series Checked Out Id",
            "extensions": null,
            "firstValue": null,
            "id": "cmis:versionSeriesCheckedOutId",
            "localName": "versionSeriesCheckedOutId",
            "queryName": "cmis:versionSeriesCheckedOutId",
            "values": []
        },
        {
            "displayName": "Is private working copy",
            "extensions": null,
            "firstValue": null,
            "id": "cmis:isPrivateWorkingCopy",
            "localName": "isPrivateWorkingCopy",
            "queryName": "cmis:isPrivateWorkingCopy",
            "values": []
        },
        {
            "displayName": "Version series id",
            "extensions": null,
            "firstValue": "cc8c446f-ac4e-40e5-b040-08f1030b708e",
            "id": "cmis:versionSeriesId",
            "localName": "versionSeriesId",
            "queryName": "cmis:versionSeriesId",
            "values": [
                "cc8c446f-ac4e-40e5-b040-08f1030b708e"
            ]
        },
        {
            "displayName": "Version Label",
            "extensions": null,
            "firstValue": "1.0",
            "id": "cmis:versionLabel",
            "localName": "versionLabel",
            "queryName": "cmis:versionLabel",
            "values": [
                "1.0"
            ]
        },
        {
            "displayName": "Is Latest Version",
            "extensions": null,
            "firstValue": true,
            "id": "cmis:isLatestVersion",
            "localName": "isLatestVersion",
            "queryName": "cmis:isLatestVersion",
            "values": [
                true
            ]
        },
        {
            "displayName": "Is Version Series Checked Out",
            "extensions": null,
            "firstValue": false,
            "id": "cmis:isVersionSeriesCheckedOut",
            "localName": "isVersionSeriesCheckedOut",
            "queryName": "cmis:isVersionSeriesCheckedOut",
            "values": [
                false
            ]
        },
        {
            "displayName": "Last Modified By",
            "extensions": null,
            "firstValue": "admin",
            "id": "cmis:lastModifiedBy",
            "localName": "lastModifiedBy",
            "queryName": "cmis:lastModifiedBy",
            "values": [
                "admin"
            ]
        },
        {
            "displayName": "Created by",
            "extensions": null,
            "firstValue": "admin",
            "id": "cmis:createdBy",
            "localName": "createdBy",
            "queryName": "cmis:createdBy",
            "values": [
                "admin"
            ]
        },
        {
            "displayName": "Alfresco Node Ref",
            "extensions": null,
            "firstValue": "workspace://SpacesStore/cc8c446f-ac4e-40e5-b040-08f1030b708e",
            "id": "alfcmis:nodeRef",
            "localName": "nodeRef",
            "queryName": "alfcmis:nodeRef",
            "values": [
                "workspace://SpacesStore/cc8c446f-ac4e-40e5-b040-08f1030b708e"
            ]
        },
        {
            "displayName": "Is Latest Major Version",
            "extensions": null,
            "firstValue": true,
            "id": "cmis:isLatestMajorVersion",
            "localName": "isLatestMajorVersion",
            "queryName": "cmis:isLatestMajorVersion",
            "values": [
                true
            ]
        },
        {
            "displayName": "Content Stream Id",
            "extensions": null,
            "firstValue": "store://2014/5/29/11/37/64b37543-290c-4800-9b01-dfa76569a031.bin",
            "id": "cmis:contentStreamId",
            "localName": "contentStreamId",
            "queryName": "cmis:contentStreamId",
            "values": [
                "store://2014/5/29/11/37/64b37543-290c-4800-9b01-dfa76569a031.bin"
            ]
        },
        {
            "displayName": "Name",
            "extensions": null,
            "firstValue": "Document1.pdf",
            "id": "cmis:name",
            "localName": "name",
            "queryName": "cmis:name",
            "values": [
                "Document1.pdf"
            ]
        },
        {
            "displayName": "Content Stream MIME Type",
            "extensions": null,
            "firstValue": "application/pdf",
            "id": "cmis:contentStreamMimeType",
            "localName": "contentStreamMimeType",
            "queryName": "cmis:contentStreamMimeType",
            "values": [
                "application/pdf"
            ]
        },
        {
            "displayName": "Creation Date",
            "extensions": null,
            "firstValue": "2014-05-29T18:37:36.345+0000",
            "id": "cmis:creationDate",
            "localName": "creationDate",
            "queryName": "cmis:creationDate",
            "values": [
                "2014-05-29T18:37:36.345+0000"
            ]
        },
        {
            "displayName": "Change token",
            "extensions": null,
            "firstValue": null,
            "id": "cmis:changeToken",
            "localName": "changeToken",
            "queryName": "cmis:changeToken",
            "values": []
        },
        {
            "displayName": "Secondary Object Type Ids",
            "extensions": null,
            "firstValue": "P:cm:thumbnailModification",
            "id": "cmis:secondaryObjectTypeIds",
            "localName": "secondaryObjectTypeIds",
            "queryName": "cmis:secondaryObjectTypeIds",
            "values": [
                "P:cm:thumbnailModification",
                "P:cm:titled",
                "P:cm:author",
                "P:rn:renditioned",
                "P:sys:localized"
            ]
        },
        {
            "displayName": "Checkin Comment",
            "extensions": null,
            "firstValue": null,
            "id": "cmis:checkinComment",
            "localName": "checkinComment",
            "queryName": "cmis:checkinComment",
            "values": []
        },
        {
            "displayName": "Object Id",
            "extensions": null,
            "firstValue": "cc8c446f-ac4e-40e5-b040-08f1030b708e;1.0",
            "id": "cmis:objectId",
            "localName": "objectId",
            "queryName": "cmis:objectId",
            "values": [
                "cc8c446f-ac4e-40e5-b040-08f1030b708e;1.0"
            ]
        },
        {
            "displayName": "Is Immutable",
            "extensions": null,
            "firstValue": false,
            "id": "cmis:isImmutable",
            "localName": "isImmutable",
            "queryName": "cmis:isImmutable",
            "values": [
                false
            ]
        },
        {
            "displayName": "Is Major Version",
            "extensions": null,
            "firstValue": true,
            "id": "cmis:isMajorVersion",
            "localName": "isMajorVersion",
            "queryName": "cmis:isMajorVersion",
            "values": [
                true
            ]
        },
        {
            "displayName": "Base Type Id",
            "extensions": null,
            "firstValue": "cmis:document",
            "id": "cmis:baseTypeId",
            "localName": "baseTypeId",
            "queryName": "cmis:baseTypeId",
            "values": [
                "cmis:document"
            ]
        },
        {
            "displayName": "Description",
            "extensions": null,
            "firstValue": null,
            "id": "cmis:description",
            "localName": "description",
            "queryName": "cmis:description",
            "values": []
        },
        {
            "displayName": "Last Modified Date",
            "extensions": null,
            "firstValue": "2014-05-29T18:37:36.345+0000",
            "id": "cmis:lastModificationDate",
            "localName": "lastModificationDate",
            "queryName": "cmis:lastModificationDate",
            "values": [
                "2014-05-29T18:37:36.345+0000"
            ]
        },
        {
            "displayName": "Content Stream Filename",
            "extensions": null,
            "firstValue": "Document1.pdf",
            "id": "cmis:contentStreamFileName",
            "localName": "contentStreamFileName",
            "queryName": "cmis:contentStreamFileName",
            "values": [
                "Document1.pdf"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```